# Book for balance sheet reading?

Tags: financial-literacy, balance-sheet, books

What is an easy to understand book that teaches a beginner how to read a balance sheet? Something like a Balance Sheet for Dummies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By a remarkable coincidence, there actually is a title "Balance Sheets for Dummies".
I've not read this particular title, but the series has yet to disappoint. 
If you'd like a start, the 6 page [A Beginner's Guide to the Balance Sheet](http://ufdcimages.uflib.ufl.edu/IR/00/00/18/44/00001/FE15300.pdf) is a decent article.

Comment: Google Books does not even have the title "Balance Sheets for Dummies".......... https://www.google.com/search?q=Balance+Sheets+for+Dummies&tbm=bks

Comment: Perhaps it's out of print. This question is two years old.

Comment: Google Books archive even books that are out of print. I doubt the book "Balance Sheets for Dummies" even exist.... Do you mean "accounting for dummies"?

Comment: Accounting for Dummies should cover the topic.

Answer (score 2):

I found this yesterday which is really beginner friendly in the way it breaks each part down into layman terms. Really helped me a lot.

**[A Simple Guide to Understanding Your Company's Financial Statements](http://www.wbdc.org/Portals/0/Resources%20and%20Tools/Understanding%20Your%20Business%20Financial%20Statements.pdf)** by Illinois Small Business Development Center

Screenshot from inside:

[image]

(if link ever goes dead ping me and I can share through PDFy or Google Drive)

Answer (score 1):

I think [Investopedia.com](http://www.investopedia.com) is one of the best resources for beginners.

[Heres](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/04/031004.asp) a good tutorial on balance sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing beats Security Analysis by Benjamin Graham. Especially the 1941 Edition, is the best.

Its very tough to read it, but if you do it will be incredibly transforming.