# Useful insights to be gleaned from balance sheets, income statements, and cash flow

Tags: investing, stock-analysis

I'm trying to teach myself how to glean insights relevant to investing in a company from looking at the company's balance sheets and income statements over time. I think this may be considered part of Fundamental Analysis. I found [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/8591/94726) and despite being closed, it was helpful to me for understanding what to look for and insights available from the balance sheet.

Can anyone recommend similar authoritative resources for understanding and gleaning important insights from a company's income statements and cash flow (and others too, for balance sheets)?

I find that obtaining these data sources is trivial, but understanding them and gleaning important insights from them is not trivial for me.